# Embeddable formula interpreter

Tags: c++, c, jit, embedding, formulas

I need something to embed in my C/C++ program to interpret formulas of the like x*log(x) or sin(x). I would like something small and simple, otherwise I can just embed Python, or Ch, or Scheme, or you name it. But all I need is simple formulas. I have searched the web without luck. Although I don't require it, performance (e.g., the use of a simple JIT) would be a bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lua](http://www.lua.org) - is by far the simplest to embed and use and there *is* a very small and **very fast** version with a JIT: http://luajit.org/

Comment: I have successfully assimilated luajit in my code now. Although I needed a couple of hours for figuring out that luaL_loadbuffer needs a luaL_pcall after it....other than that it works o.k.

Comment: Cool! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 5):

Use Reverse Polish notation. There are few algorithms:
1. Parse equation and convert to infix notation (that is easy, you simply identify chain of symbols)
2. Using Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm convert infix to RPN.
3. Using DFS calculate the expression

I'm sure there is a lot implementations on the net. I even wrote my own few years ago (without functions feature).

Answer (score 4):

An excellent portable language for this sort of thing is JavaScript. There are more than a few implementations to choose from, for C and C++ there are at least:

- [QtScript](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qtscript.html)
- [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)

Another easily embeddable choice might be [Lua](http://lua.org). It's certainly easier to use something that already exists rather than reinventing an expression parser.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg has a very nice one which you should check out.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing your own simple stack-machine for calculating such formulas?